# Why does Google Finance show the NASDAQ Composite way up but Yahoo! Finance shows it slightly down?

Tags: quotes, yahoo-finance, google-finance, nasdaq

[Google Finance](https://www.google.com/finance?q=INDEXNASDAQ%3a.IXIC) versus [Yahoo! Finance](http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=%5Eixic). I'm sure the difference is because Google Finance shows a date of November 8 while Yahoo! Finance shows November 9. But aren't the markets closed on Saturday?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First - Google's snapshot -

[image: Google]

Then - Yahoo -

[image]

I took these snapshots because they will not exist on line after the market opens, and without this context, your question won't make sense.

With the two snapshots you can see, Yahoo shows the after hours trades and not just the official market close for the day. The amount it's down is exactly tracked from the close shown on Google. Now you know.

Comment: I figured that was the reason, but after-hours trading doesn't extend to Saturdays does it? And why would Yahoo include that in their quote? Seems likely to confuse people...big difference between +1.60% and -0.03%.

Comment: No trading on Saturday. I agree, it's odd they put up a Saturday date.

Comment: After hours trades on Friday night, though.

Comment: @CraigW, an API should always offer the last available quote for the timeframe they cover, even if you query after hours.  The same is true if I go to the CME website and ask for a quote on Saturday; for instance, click this [S&P 500 eMini quote](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/us-index/e-mini-sandp500.html) on Saturday and observe that they still give you Friday's last trade info (as well as the timestamp for the info).